# Hebrew calendar control

Tags: .net, winforms, localization

In asp.net there is a build-in option to change the calendar control to Hebrew, is there a easy way of doing it in winForms too?

Answer (score 1):

No easy way found yet; need to use(or create) custom control.

Though Hebrew calendar is supported well by the System.Globalization.HebrewCalendar.

Comment: any clue how to create that control?

Comment: You should try to inherit from existing control and re-implement its methods/properties. I don't know how much flexible DateTimePicker is, but anyway - control is just combinations of other controls. There's MSDN's tutorial; I'm pretty sure that there should be more on this topic http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207%28v=vs.71%29.aspx